# Unable to use percentages inside of my Keyframe animation transformations

Tags: next.js, css-animations, tailwind-css

Currently I'm trying to add an animation to a page of a few shooting stars flying across the screen. I want the star to appear and end at certain percentages of the available screen to make it responsive and visible on any device. However when I try to do this, my values seem to default to 0px rather than the percentage that I am passing into my `tailwind.config.js` from my React Component. The values work if I pass in pixels, but as I mentioned, I would rather do percentages so that it can work well on any screen.

Currently, I am passing in my desired percentage values using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72894718/21190297) with an alteration to make it React compatible like this:

```
style={{"--startingX":props.startingX}}
```

I am currently using NextJS and TailwindCSS to attempt to make this.

Here are (what I believe are) the relevant files:

`/components/shootingStar.js`

```
export default function ShootingStar(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <div style={{"--percentage":props.startingX}} className="absolute animate-star">
                <div className="transform absolute top-2/4 ..."></div>
                <div className="absolute top-full left-2/4 ..."></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

animation: 'star' is the animation in question, inside of keyframes I created my custom animation.

`tailwind.config.js`:

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        'Quicksand': ['Quicksand', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      }, 
      'animation': {
        ...
        star : "star 3s linear infinite"
      },
      'keyframes': {
        ...
          star: {
            '0%' : {
              transform : 'translateX(var(--percentage)) translateY(0px) rotate(235deg)',
              'opacity': '50%'
            },
            '75%' : {
              'opacity' : '100%'
            },
            '100%' : {
              transform : 'translateX(350px) translateY(500px) rotate(235deg)',
              'opacity' : '0%'
            }
          }
        }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

`index.js`

```
  return (
    //This div is the parent div to the whole page which is why I included it.
    <div className="bg-gradient-to-tl from-blue-900 to-black overflow-x-auto h-screen w-screen ">
        <ShootingStar startingX={'25%'} startingY={'25%'} endingX={'500px'} endingY={'500px'}</ShootingStar>
        {The remaining shooting stars would eventually get created here}
    </div>
...
)
```

When the animation is at 0%, I would like my star component to start at a specified X% of my screen (for example if I pass in 25% to my percentage var, I would like it to start 1/4 of the way into the screen from the left hand side of the window.)

If this is possible, I plan to expand this for the starting Y value and the ending values of X & Y as well which is why I have those props passed in.

If I pass in 25% to my percentage var, my starting value is at the top left of the screen (or 0). and allows the animation to run. If I try to hardcode percentage values into my Keyframe animation, the animation does not occur since all of the values are technically defaulting to 0.

I am expecting the animation to start at 1/4 of the way in from the left hand side.

I feel as if I'm doing something slightly wrong that won't allow me to make this animation possible but I am not entirely sure what that would be.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why my animation was stuck in the top left after further research. Keyframe animations take the height and width specifications of the component that is being animated, and do not inherit their parent's height or width (as I initially thought they did). Because I had not specified a height or width for my component it could not move across the screen as I originally wanted it to.

For anyone who might run into this as I did make sure you are setting the height and width of your components to allow your animation to go through your component. Otherwise, if you want it to run through your entire viewport, use `vh` rather than `%` when setting your animation values.

Regardless, I decided to opt for viewport since it better fits my use case.